# Why is the line that passes through zero a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the textbook 'Convex Optimization by Boyd', the following statement is written:

- Any line is affine. If it passes through zero, it is a subspace, hence also a convex cone.

I agree with the statements, "line is affine.", and "It is also a convex cone.".
However, I cannot understand the above statement. Please let me know that statement. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: What part don't you understand? The subspace part?

Comment: @quasi Exactly YES!! subspace is just sub-space... NO??  If $A=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $B=\mathbb{R}^2$, then $B$ is a subspace of $A$, right?

Comment: Yes, but so is any line through the origin. If a line passes through the origin, the nonzero vectors corresponding to points on the line are all scalar multiples of any chosen one of them, thus form a 1-dimensional subspace of the given space.

Comment: Also, any plane through the origin is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: So saying that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not quite right. More accurate is that any $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (i.e., plane through the origin) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus, there are infinitely many subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$, each isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: The $1$-dimensional subspaces of $R^3$ are analogous, except they're lines through the origin, and they're all isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @quasi Hmm... isomorphic!! I have seen that word in the graph theory textbook. You mean $\mathbb{R}^2$ with passing through origin is exadct subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and other plane is isomorphic to it.. right??

Comment: Isomorphic as in isomorphic vector spaces. Two vector spaces are isomorphic if there is a bijective linear map from one to the other. It means that the vector space "structure" is the same, even if the underlying sets of points are different.

Comment: For example, a line through the origin has the same structure, from a vector space perspective, as $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks, then is it correct that "all subspaces has the origin."

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: You might need to review some linear algebra -- especially the vector space concepts, so as not to have knowledge gaps in the course you're taking..

Comment: @quasi I couldn't agree with you more!! Thank you very much.

Comment: As quasi pointed out, $\mathbb R^2$ is not strictly speaking a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. The former consists of ordered pairs and the other of ordered triples, so there’s no element of $\mathbb R^2$ that is also an element of $\mathbb R^3$. However, the set of vectors of the form $(x,y,0)$, i.e., the $x$-$y$ plane, *is* a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ and is obviously isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @amd Thank you for giving me more strict explanation. Can I ask in which subject (class) or textbook can I learn isomorphic notion easily but in detail? Actually, I am not majoring in Mathematics but in Engineering. So, I maybe need to study myself if the professor does not allow me to take a class held in the other department's.

Comment: The powerful idea of isomorphism pervades mathematics. Fundamentally, it’s a bijective map that preserves some structure that we’re interested in. For vector spaces, an isomorphism is a linear transformation that preserves the vectors space structure (often, other things such as inner products, too). Any basic linear algebra text will cover this.

Comment: This case is illustrative. A plane through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$, so that as vector spaces they have identical properties and can in many ways be treated interchangeably. They’re not really identical, though, since the former is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$, but the latter isn’t. That distinction may or may not be important depending on context.